# Analytics API + Python Server, NotImplementedError Hello Analytics

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

A little background: I've been trying to make a restful server that can query and insert via the management API.  After banging my head against the wall using node.js and javascript I switched over to python knowing it has more support.

Currently I am trying to follow the GA [Tutorial: Hello Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) with a slight twist. I trigger the what was the `main` method in `hello_analytics_api_v3.py` when trying to access a particular end point on the server.  This is only for testing. The method is called `insertExperiment` and attempts to insert an experiment into a private Google Analytics account.

However I'm always receiving the exception:
`NotImplementedError('The gflags library must be installed to use tools.run(). Please install gflags or preferrably switch to using tools.run_flow().',)`

Here is the full trace stack:

> File "/0zzz/bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
>
> ```
> return route.call(**args)
> ```
>
> File "/0zzz/bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
>
> ```
> rv = callback(*a, **ka)
> ```
>
> File "server.py", line 39, in server_static
>
> ```
> hello_analytics_api_v3.insertExperiment("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxx", experiment_body)
> ```
>
> File "/0zzz/hello_analytics_api_v3.py", line 11, in insertExperiment
>
> ```
> service = hello_analytics_api_v3_auth.initialize_service()
> ```
>
> File "/0zzz/hello_analytics_api_v3_auth.py", line 32, in
>   initialize_service
>
> ```
> credentials = prepare_credentials()
> ```
>
> File "/0zzz/hello_analytics_api_v3_auth.py", line 25, in
>   prepare_credentials
>
> ```
> credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
> ```
>
> File "/0zzz/oauth2client/tools.py", line 241, in run
>
> ```
> 'The gflags library must be installed to use tools.run(). '
> ```
>
> NotImplementedError: The gflags library must be installed to use
>   tools.run(). Please install gflags or preferrably switch to using
>   tools.run_flow().

**A few extra notes:**

- I have tried this exact same thing (invoking `main` on pinging the correct address) when copying the exact code from the Tutorial.
- I have write access with the management API -- so that's not a problem here at all.
- I thought there might be a namespace issue with one of my libraries (which also imports a `run`) but resolved this by renaming the other library.
- GA Client Library is installed! as per the instructions on [Hello Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api).

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 11):

I received the same error while running through a tutorial for google APIs called 'Google APIs Console Help'. The fix was simple in my case, just update the gflags library:

easy_install --upgrade python-gflags

Comment: or - of course - `sudo apt-get install python-gflags`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install gflags library.

$ wget https://python-gflags.googlecode.com/files/python-gflags-2.0.tar.gz

$ tar xfvz python-gflags-2.0.tar.gz ; cd python-gflags-2.0

$ python setup.py install